# How to properly test simple effects: factor recode or data subsetting

Tags: regression, interaction, linear-model

I have seen people test their simple effects in two different ways and would like to know which is the correct one and why. The two methods are briefly explained below:

- **recoding method**: Involves recoding the moderating factor (e.g. `Species`) such that the level of interest (e.g. `versicolor`) is set to `0` and testing the complete model (e.g. `Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Width * Species`).
- **subsetting method**: Involves subsetting the dataset such that it only contains the level of interest (e.g. `versicolor`) and testing the simple relation between your IV and DV (e.g. `Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Width`).

Here is an exemple to illustrate the idea:

```
library(data.table)
X <- data.table(iris)
X <- X[Species %in% c("setosa", "versicolor"), .(Petal.Width, Sepal.Width, Species)]
X[, Species := factor(Species)] # reset factors

contrasts(X$Species) <- cbind(Setosa_vs_Versicolor = c(-.5, +.5)) # contrast coded
mdl <- lm(data = X, Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Width * Species)

# Simple effect for Species = versicolor
contrasts(X$Species) <- cbind(versicolor = c(1, 0))
mdl.simple1 <- lm(data = X, Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Width * Species)
mdl.simple2 <- lm(data = X[Species == "versicolor"], Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Width)
```

The interaction is significant:

```
> summary(mdl)

Call:
lm(formula = Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Width * Species, data = X)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.29671 -0.07348 -0.03125  0.06552  0.41251 

Coefficients:
                                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                              0.09554    0.11674   0.818    0.415    
Sepal.Width                              0.24158    0.03798   6.360 6.82e-09 ***
SpeciesSetosa_vs_Versicolor              0.14273    0.23347   0.611    0.542    
Sepal.Width:SpeciesSetosa_vs_Versicolor  0.35374    0.07597   4.657 1.03e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1285 on 96 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9498,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9483 
F-statistic:   606 on 3 and 96 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Results for the *recoding method*:

```
> summary(mdl.simple1) # factor recoding

Call:
lm(formula = Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Width * Species, data = X)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.29671 -0.07348 -0.03125  0.06552  0.41251 

Coefficients:
                              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                    0.16691    0.16311   1.023    0.309    
Sepal.Width                    0.41845    0.05852   7.151 1.70e-10 ***
Speciesversicolor             -0.14273    0.23347  -0.611    0.542    
Sepal.Width:Speciesversicolor -0.35374    0.07597  -4.657 1.03e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1285 on 96 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9498,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9483 
F-statistic:   606 on 3 and 96 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Results for the *subsetting method*:

```
> summary(mdl.simple2) # subsetting

Call:
lm(formula = Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Width, data = X[Species == "versicolor"])

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.29671 -0.08571 -0.03040  0.07776  0.41251 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.16691    0.18958   0.880    0.383    
Sepal.Width  0.41845    0.06801   6.152 1.47e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1494 on 48 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4409,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4292 
F-statistic: 37.85 on 1 and 48 DF,  p-value: 1.467e-07
```

As you can see, the coefficients estimates are exactly the same, however the SE is smaller for the *recoding method*, thus there seem to be a gain of statistical power in this case.

Comment: In your answer, can you describe in simple words - not just R code - what each of the two methods is intended to do?

Comment: @IsabellaGhement I edited my post

Comment: Please see my answer and thank you for your edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my view best method to estimate simple effects and test their significance following the detection of a significant interaction effect is as illustrated by the R code below. [By best method, I mean a method which allows one to track very clearly what is estimated/tested in relation to the model which included the significant interaction.]  There must be an R package out there which performs this type of estimation/testing, but it's worth it to see the step-by-step method.

```
#=================================================================
# Fit Full Model 
#=================================================================

m <- lm(Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Width * Species, data=iris)

summary(m)
```

Here is the summary of the full model (with the Parameter column inserted by myself):

```
> summary(m)

Call:
lm(formula = Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Width * Species, data = iris)

Residuals:
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.45473 -0.08236 -0.02478  0.09005  0.45368 

Coefficients:
                          Parameter Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                   beta0  0.02418    0.22231   0.109 0.913542    
Sepal.Width                   beta1  0.06471    0.06447   1.004 0.317176    
Speciesversicolor             beta2  0.14273    0.31071   0.459 0.646666    
Speciesvirginica              beta3  0.63988    0.31747   2.016 0.045709  
Sepal.Width:Speciesversicolor beta4  0.35374    0.10110   3.499 0.000622 
Sepal.Width:Speciesvirginica  beta5  0.39324    0.09949   3.953 0.000121 
---

Residual standard error: 0.1711 on 144 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9513,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9496 
F-statistic: 562.9 on 5 and 144 DF,  p-value: < 0.00000000000000022


#=================================================================
# Test Significance of Interaction between Sepal.Width and Species 
#=================================================================

require(car)

Anova(m)



#=================================================================
# Specify the Model Equation for the Full Model 
#=================================================================

levels(iris$Species)

# Petal.Width = beta0 + beta1*Sepal.Width + 
#               beta2*Speciesversicolor  + 
#               beta3*Speciesvirginica + 
#               beta4*Sepal.Width:Speciesversicolor +
#               beta5*Sepal.Width:Speciesvirginica + error 

#===========================================================================
#  Specify the Model Equation for the Sub-Model 
#  Corresponding to Species = setosa 
#  [Obtained by setting Speciesversicolor = 0 & Speciesvirginica = 0 
#  in the Full Model Equation]
#===========================================================================

# Petal.Width = beta0 + beta1*Sepal.Width + error 

# --> simple effect of Sepal.Width on Petal.Width for Species = setosa 
#     is given by beta1

#==========================================================================
# Specify the Model Equation for the Sub-Model Corresponding to 
# Species = versicolor 
# [Obtained by setting Speciesversicolor = 1 & Speciesvirginica = 0 in the 
# in the Full Model Equation]
#==========================================================================

# Petal.Width = (beta0 + beta2) + (beta1 + beta4)*Sepal.Width + error 

# --> simple effect of Sepal.Width on Petal.Width for Species = setosa 
# is given by beta1 + beta4 


#==========================================================================
# Specify the Model Equation for the Sub-Model Corresponding to 
#  Species = virginica 
# [Obtained by setting Speciesversicolor = 0 & Speciesvirginica = 1 in the 
# Full Model Equation]
#==========================================================================

# Petal.Width = (beta0 + beta3) + (beta1 + beta5)*Sepal.Width + error 
# --> simple effect of Sepal.Width on Petal.Width for Species = setosa 
# is given by beta1 + beta5

#===========================================================================
# Plot the simple effect of Sepal.Width on Petal.Width for each 
# iris Species 
#===========================================================================

require(effects)

plot(allEffects(m), as.table=TRUE, layout = c(3,1))

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

#===========================================================================
# Estimate the simple effects beta1, beta1 + beta4 and beta1 + beta5 and 
# also test the null hypothesis Ho: simple effect is zero vs. 
# the alernative hypothesis Ha: simple effect is different from zero 
# for each simple effect of interest  
#===========================================================================

#--- Specify the simple effects as linear combinations of the parameters 
# beta0, beta1, beta3, beta4 and beta5 of the Full Model:
#
#   beta1 = 0*beta0 + 1*beta1 + 0*beta2 + 0*beta3 + 0*beta4 + 0*beta5 
#
#   beta1 + beta4 = 0*beta0 + 1*beta1 + 0*beta2 + 0*beta3 + 1*beta4 + 
#                   0*beta5 
#   beta1 + beta5 = 0*beta0 + 1*beta1 + 0*beta2 + 0*beta3 + 0*beta4 + 
#                   1*beta5 

c <- rep(0, length(coef(m)))
names(c) <- names(coef(m))
names(c)
c

#--- define c1 to contain the coefficients (0 or 1) used to define beta1  
#--- where c1 = c(0,1,0,0,0,0)

c1 <- c
c1[names(c) %in% "Sepal.Width"] <- 1    
c1

#--- define c2 to contain the coefficients (0 or 1) used to define 
#    beta1 + beta4 where c2 = c(0,1,0,0,1,0)
#--- 

c2 <- c
c2[names(c) %in% "Sepal.Width"] <- 1
c2[names(c) %in% "Sepal.Width:Speciesversicolor"] <- 1  
c2

#--- define c3 to contain the coefficients (0 or 1) used to define 
#    beta1 + beta5 where c3 = c(0,1,0,0,0,1)
#---

c3 <- c
c3[names(c) %in% "Sepal.Width"] <- 1
c3[names(c) %in% "Sepal.Width:Speciesvirginica"] <- 1  
c3

#--- Combine c1, c2 and c3 into one matrix

require(multcomp)

contr <- rbind(c1, c2, c3)

contr

rownames(contr) <- c("c1", "c2", "c3")
colnames(contr) <-  rownames(coef(m))

contr

# Estimate the simple effects and test their significance 

glht.obj <- glht(m, linfct = contr)

summary(glht.obj, test = adjusted(type = "none"))

confint(glht.obj)
```

The subsetting method is indeed less powerful, though it provides a quick and dirty way of investigating the simple effects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! `plot(allEffects(m))` is a really nice way to visualize the simple effects.